# Make 2 pointer point to the same adress with google tests actions

Tags: unit-testing, glib, googlemock

I need to test the case where [g_ascii_strtoll](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-ascii-strtoll) fails and sets both pointers to the same value, set errno to 0 and return 0 (According to the doc : "*If the string conversion fails, zero is returned, and endptr returns nptr (if endptr is non-NULL)*")  (even if output_str = NULL in my case)
My code to test:

```
gchar* output_ptr= NULL;
gchar* input_ptr= "f";
result = g_ascii_strtoll(input_ptr, &output_ptr, 10);
```

My Google test snippet:

```
const gchar* nptr;
EXPECT_CALL(mock_gstring, g_ascii_strtoll(_,_,_)).WillOnce( DoAll(SaveArg<0>(&nptr), SetArgReferee<1>((char)*nptr), SetErrnoAndReturn(0,0))  );
```

Basically, I just want to do `*output_ptr= (gchar *)input_ptr;` but with Google tests actions but I don't manage to make it work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue by using [Invoke(f)](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cheat_sheet.html#using-a-function-functor-or-lambda-as-an-action).
So, instead of :

```
const gchar* nptr;
EXPECT_CALL(mock_gstring, g_ascii_strtoll(_,_,_)).WillOnce( DoAll(SaveArg<0>(&nptr), SetArgReferee<1>((char)*nptr), SetErrnoAndReturn(0,0))  );
```

I did this :

```
void ut_pointer_cpy(const gchar *nptr, gchar **endptr, guint base){
    *endptr= (gchar *)nptr;
}
EXPECT_CALL(mock_gstring, g_ascii_strtoll(_,_,_))
            .WillOnce( DoAll(Invoke(ut_pointer_cpy), SetErrnoAndReturn(0,0))  );
```

The function you call in `Invoke` must have the same parameters as the one you mock, or use `Unused` keywork instead (I didn't test this option).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what your situation is, so this may not be relevant, but here are two points (neither of which actually answers your googlemock question, sorry):

- You may find that [`g_ascii_string_to_unsigned()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-ascii-string-to-unsigned) is easier to use than `g_ascii_strtoll()`. It has equivalent functionality for the main use case of parsing the entirety of a string into an integer.
- Functions in GLib are tested in the [unit tests for GLib](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/master/glib/tests/strfuncs.c), so you shouldn’t need to write your own duplicate tests. However, if you’ve found a bug in GLib and are testing that, please consider [reporting it upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/new?issue%5Bassignee_id%5D=&issue%5Bmilestone_id%5D=) so everyone can benefit.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback ! Unfortunately I don't have the chance to choose the function to test, but I'll suggest it to my team. We have to provide the unit tests for all developments but I'll go and check how they did in the GLib unit tests

Comment: Why not just run the GLib unit tests directly?

Comment: As it is part of a bigger project, we need to cover the whole project with the same framework. TBH, i was asked to do so and I'm still new on the job so I didn't question to much ...